# Angular - Reactive form Regular expression is not accepting special character after alphanumeric character

Tags: angular, regex

I have a reactive form, suppose I enter any special character it should not accept, Suppose I enter special character with alphanumeric character it should accept. Till now working fine but when I enter special character after alphanumeric character form is not accepting. Here is code below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-f3lsts?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html

### app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-1">
      <form [formGroup]="SignupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div formGroupName="userData">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">UserName</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="username"
              formControlName="username"
            />
            <span
              class="help-block"
              *ngIf="
                !SignupForm.get('userData.username').valid &&
                SignupForm.get('userData.username').touched
              "
            >
              <span
                *ngIf="
                  SignupForm.get('userData.username').errors['nameIsForbidden']
                "
                >name is invalid</span
              >
              <span
                *ngIf="SignupForm.get('userData.username').errors['pattern']"
                >field is required</span
              >
            </span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              class="form-control"
              id="email"
              formControlName="email"
            />

            <span
              class="help-block"
              *ngIf="
                !SignupForm.get('userData.email').valid &&
                SignupForm.get('userData.email').touched
              "
            >
              please enter a valid email id
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" [value]="gender" formControlName="gender" />{{
              gender
            }}
          </label>
        </div>

        <div formArrayName="hobbies">
          <h4>Hobbies</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="onAddHobby()">
            Add Hobby
          </button>

          <div
            class="form-group"
            *ngFor="
              let hobbyControl of SignupForm.get('hobbies').controls;
              let i = index
            "
          >
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <span
          class="help-block"
          *ngIf="!SignupForm.valid && SignupForm.touched"
        >
          please enter valid data
        </span>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  genders = ['male', 'female'];
  SignupForm: FormGroup;
  // forbiddenUserNames=['geetha','puja'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.SignupForm = new FormGroup({
      userData: new FormGroup({
        username: new FormControl('', [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern(/[\w\s!^\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669]$/),
        ]),
        email: new FormControl(
          null,
          [Validators.required, Validators.email],
          this.forbiddenEmails
        ),
      }),
      gender: new FormControl('female'),
      hobbies: new FormArray([]),
    });

    this.SignupForm.setValue({
      userData: {
        username: 'geetha',
        email: 'geetha@gmail.com',
      },
      gender: 'female',
      hobbies: [],
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.SignupForm);
  }

  onAddHobby() {
    const control = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
    (<FormArray>this.SignupForm.get('hobbies')).push(control);
  }

  forbiddenNames(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    if (this.forbiddenUserNames.indexOf(control.value) != -1) {
      return { nameisForbidden: true };
    }

    return null;
  }

  forbiddenEmails(control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
    const promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (control.value === 'test@test.com') {
          resolve({ emailIsForbidden: true });
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      }, 1500);
    });
    return promise;
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like the regex you're using `/[\w\s!^\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669]$/` is causing this problem.

Comment: try your regex with https://www.regextester.com/ one thing I did note is that this regex only seems to work for 1 character at a time. If you add a * before the $ it would 0 or more of the preceding regex.

Comment: If I put * before $ it is accepting special characters also